# Erro ao executar TimerTask JavaFx

Tags: thread, javafx, timer

Estou tentando executar uma tarefa de 1 em 1 minuto. A tarefa é executada porém quando chega no minuto certo para realizar a ação da essa exceção:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = Timer-0

Resumindo, tenho um método que pega a hora do sistema e verifica se é igual a hora do banco, se as horas forem iguais um alerta é exibido. Estava tudo funcionando antes de colocar no TimerTask, O método `alertaGeral();` é chamado e funciona desde que não esta com as Horas iguais, quando as horas são iguais o alerta deveria ser exibido porém da o erro.

Meu método:

```
 private void executarTarefa() {
        //****INICIA A TAREFA ELE VERIFICA A CADA UM MINUTO****//  
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
        System.out.println("Iniciado!");

        Timer timer = null;
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        alertaGeral();
                        System.out.println("Alertado..");
                        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, TEMPO, TEMPO);
        }

        }
   });

    }
```

Comment: Tudo que você coloca na TimerTask é executado em uma thread paralela, você provavelmente está tentando utilizar algum objeto que está sendo utilizado pela thread principal. Terá que parar de utilizar esse objeto ou criar uma cópia dele e usá-la.

Comment: Eu estou tentando usar uma `Lista<Tarefas>`. Eu uso a mesma lista pra preencher minha tabela

Comment: Então, não acredito que poderá utilizar a mesma lista, pois a threads são concorrentes. Tente fazer com uma cópia, mas qualquer alteração feita nessa lista ou nos itens dela não será refletida na original.

Comment: onde está seu método `executarTarefa()` e sua tabela?

Comment: Acho que encontrei o erro, vou fazer um teste. O erro pode estar nessa linha:`Alert dialogoAviso = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    dialogoAviso.setTitle("AVISO1");
                    dialogoAviso.setHeaderText("Voce tem um compromisso marcado para: " + c.getDataExibicao() + " as " + c.getHoraInicial());
                    dialogoAviso.setContentText("Compromisso: " + c.getCompromisso() + "\nNome do Beneficiário: " + c.getNomeBeneficiario());
                    dialogoAviso.showAndWait();`

Comment: Eu estou usando esse Alert dentro do método `alertaGeral();` e o método `executaTarefa` está no construtor